# Can you explain the order of execution in the code mentioned below?

Tags: javascript

```js
function makeMultiplier (multiplier){
    var myFunc = function (x){
        return multiplier * x;
    }
    return myFunc;
}

var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);
console.log(makeMultiplier(3)(10));
```

Here, I don't understand why and how does the var multiplyBy3 variable acts as a reference to the myFunc function mentioned above

Comment: Have you tried adding `debugger` and debugging the code?

Comment: Have you understood the execution order and your subsequent question?

Answer (score 0):

Order of execution:

1. `makeMultiplier` is defined
2. `makeMultiplier` is called with arg 3 and returns a new function and that returned function is stored in a variable named `multiplyBy3`.
3. console log called with `makeMultiplier` is called with 3, returns a new function and it is called with argument 10

In JavaScript all the non primitive objects' assignments are stored as reference, but not as value. Example variable assignments, argument passing to functions where  it basically assigned to the parameter which is a local variable inside the function.

However, second call to the `multiplier` with arg 3 is a different function, the references are different.

Also you can test those with `Object.is()` static method.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of executing the function `makeMultiplier` is function `myFunc`. This is being assigned to variable `multiplyBy3` . Hence it will act as a reference to `myFunc` function

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you don't actually use `multiplyBy3`, but here's your code modified to use it as the reference to the inner `myFunc(3)`:

```js
function makeMultiplier(multiplier) {
  var myFunc = function(x) {
    return multiplier * x;
  }
  return myFunc;
}
var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);
console.log(multiplyBy3(10));
```

When setting the `multiplyBy3` variable, we call the `makeMultiplier` function with `3` as our `multiplier` argument. This returns a reference to `function(x) { return 3 * x; }` which is assigned to `multiplyBy3`.

Calling `multiplyBy3(10)` then results in the value of `30` due to multiplying `3` by the argument of `10`. This is equivalent to your original code `makeMultiplier(3)(10)`

In the following code snippet, I modified your code to use `multiplyBy3` and threw in some `console.log` statements to show the steps taken both outside and inside the functions.

```js
function makeMultiplier(multiplier) {
  console.log("[enter] makeMultiplier");
  var myFunc = function(x) {
    console.log("[enter] myFunc");
    return multiplier * x;
  }
  return myFunc;
}
console.log("[before] 'var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);'");
var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);
console.log("[after] 'var multiplyBy3 = makeMultiplier(3);'");
console.log("[before] 'console.log(multiplyBy3(10));'");
console.log(multiplyBy3(10));
console.log("[after] 'console.log(multiplyBy3(10));'");
```

Additionally, I'll show an alternate example where we multiply by `4`:

```js
function makeMultiplier(multiplier) {
  console.log("[enter] makeMultiplier");
  var myFunc = function(x) {
    console.log("[enter] myFunc");
    return multiplier * x;
  }
  return myFunc;
}
console.log("[before] 'var multiplyBy4 = makeMultiplier(4);'");
var multiplyBy4 = makeMultiplier(4);
console.log("[after] 'var multiplyBy4 = makeMultiplier(4);'");
console.log("[before] 'console.log(multiplyBy4(10));'");
console.log(multiplyBy4(10));
console.log("[after] 'console.log(multiplyBy4(10));'");
```